# How to suppress MS Access "Do you want to save layout" dialog

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a Microsoft Access database where I'd like to be able to close the table datasheet view without it asking me if I want to save the layout. Is there a way to supress this dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In code:

```
  DoCmd.Close acTable, "MyTable", acSaveNo
```

There is no way to turn it off globally or for interactive use of the table.